# "<appname> does not validate as nameValidator" when trying to register a new uber app

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to create a new Uber app.
When I select a name for the app in https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/create, I receive an error that the name of the app does not validate as nameValidator (e.g., IdoUberDemoApp).

What are the app name validation rules?

Comment: Uber is the right entity to whom you should ask the question, but usually, it's either because the name is already taken (as it loads before validation) or because of a forbidden word (maybe "Uber"). Have you tried a different name?

Comment: Thanks, I assume the problem was including the name Uber in the app name. As for asking Uber, their support site refers to StackOverflow (using the uber-api tag).